# Pass variable to chrome extension script when installing it from chrome webstore

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am making an extension that should include in its background script some variable that should be unique for every user and that must not be altered. I was able to soolve this in Firefox since it is possible to generate the extension package inline and install it with not problems. 
As far as chrome is concerned, I cannot rely on cookies, session or localstorage since the can be erased if the user deletes his browsing history.
Then my question is very simple, is it possible to pass the variable when installing the extension from chrome webstore using a link lik this  for example : 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/search-by-image-by-google/dajedkncpodkggklbegccjpmnglmnflm?id=somevar

Comment: This is not possible. There are plenty of questions and answers on Stack Overflow that shows how to work-around the problem.

Answer (score -1):

YOu may use Sync Storage in Chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage 
It use Google Drive in background to store data. Even if the user clear browser data it will remain intact. 
The user will not see this data on Drive because they are not visible in the drive's UI (files are hidden) so probably he will not be able to delete it.

However you must consider a situation when the user is not logged in to Chrome or the user disabled sync options. In this scenario storage.sync will behave like storage.local.

Even when the user clear browsing data, the data stored in storage.local will remain. They will be deleted only on uninstall.

**Edit:**
Data are stored on Google Drive using syncFileSystem API - not storage.sync. However it doesn't change the solution I wrote.

Comment: `chrome.storage` does not save content in Drive. I think that you're confusing the [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) extension/app API with the [`chrome.syncFileSystem`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/syncFileSystem) app API.

Comment: @RobW stole my comment. Also, a savvy user can go and modify that value with relative ease, and as you said yourself the values are wiped if you uninstall.

Comment: In either case, consider editing the answer to make it more explicit that what the OP is asking is not possible, and present your current answer as an alternative / work-around, rather than THE solution to the question.

Comment: You're right! I'm confusing syncFileSystem with storage.sync. Only first one is storing data in Drive. But either way, user will not delete data clearing browsing history so in overall my response is still valid (no matter where data are stored - in this case).